# Collection Permalinks using document Front Matter title

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I have a bunch of documents in a collection that when developing, are more easily identified by their 'title code' which is why it would be best to use it as their filename (it helps keep a structure and order). Something like this:

```
_stories
    CH1S1.md
    CH1S2.md
    CH2S1.md
```

However, for the pretty urls, a slug from the document's title is better. From the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#step-3-optionally-render-your-collections-documents-into-independent-files) it seems that just using the `:title` permalink parameter is exactly what I want, but the output always uses the document's filename (as if it was using `:name` instead of `:title`).

Here is my collection definition in `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
    stories:
        output: true
        permalink: /:collection/:title/
```

Of course, in each individual document's Front Matter I am setting the title property, so I am not sure why this is not working.

I am on the latest version of Jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the permalink, instead of title, in YAML Front Matter of each file like this:

```
permalink: /stories/mystory/
```

Comment: Thanks, but obviously, and I should have specified this, I'm trying to avoid setting the permalink per-file.